# Possible to use Python as a database language?

Tags: python, sql

Many wrappers for `SQL` exist as python packages. These include `sqlite`. To me it looks like these wrappers allow the user to send `SQL` commands to databases but within a python framework. The language used is still SQL but the wrapper allows it to be sent as a string via object oriented programming.

However, is it possible to circumvent this altogether? i.e. can python itself act as a database engine? I know some `set()` commands exist in python which allow definition of lists as sets and then finding intersections, unions and differences of sets. Can this be taken further such that Python can actually send things similar to `SELECT * WHERE` statements and effectively provide all the database functionality that SQL provides? Is there maybe a library that uses python paradigm with methods and attributes that cover the same needs as a regular database engine?

Comment: check out the python-sql library https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql

Comment: See https://www.sqlalchemy.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest think to what I assume you want is the [python-sql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-sql) package. It's use is (in my novice eyes) closest to what you'd expect a databese engine's syntax would be.